# Design pattern to consume API that supports pagination

Tags: api, design-patterns, pagination

I want to get some results back from a REST API that supports pagination. The way the API works is you make the initial request and get back the following.

- List of objects
- Total Count
- Number Remaining
- Result Identifier

To get the remaining object I need to make another request passing in the results identifier and rinse and repeat.

What I am having trouble with is writing a method that does this "elegantly". I would like to have a single method where I pass in the initial query and it makes as many API calls as necessary to get back all objects and just adds them together as a single list which is returned from the method.

Are there any good design patterns to follow in this type of scenario? Do I need to use recursion for the method to call itself or is there a simpler approach? I see lots of posts on how to design an API to properly paginate but have not found anything that describes how to properly consume an API that supports pagination.